# How to press button with selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to press a button that has this inspect code:

```
<button title="Page 2" class="StyledButton-c11n-8-31-0__wpcbcc-0 inbMjV PaginationButton-c11n-8-31-0__si2hz6-0 bcxbxh">2</button>
```

I tried locating the button but it didn't work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Page 2"]').click()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"?
Can you share a link to that web page?

Comment: https://www.zillow.com/profile/JasonNadeau1/ I want to navigate to the second page under the past sales. The abovementioned code throws NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click that button you first need to scroll that element into the view.
So please try something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Page 2"]')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

After that you should be able to click on it with

```
element.click()
```

Comment: thank you, but this is the error message I get when trying: 
"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@title="Page 2"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)"

Comment: I guess you have to put some wait / delay before this code to let the page loading...

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath //*[@title='Page 2']. Double quotes could be causing the problem